# jQuery remove elements one by one

Tags: jquery

I try to do upload sistem and use Uploadify. I have onComplete function where apend images and remove buttons. Every image have own remove button, but I can't make it to remove just its image. Please help here is the code what I have. Thanks.

```
enter code here
'onComplete'  : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {

    $('#inner2').append('<img id="img" src="'+fileObj.filePath+'" width="100" height="100" /><div id="remove-btn" ><span>Remove Image</span></div>');

    $("#remove-btn").live('click',function() {

        $(this).parent().remove();

    });

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `live` when you create an element.  Use `bind` or assign the `live` handler outside of the onComplete handler.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting the [*previous*](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) image. That is, previous to the clicked div:

```
$(this).prev("img").andSelf().remove();
```

Comment: @Ivan Ivanov - edited. Pretty sure it does what you want now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().find('your image tag here').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).prev().remove();
$(this).remove();
```

As i guess you also want to remove the button as it is for an image that isnt there anymore.

Or you could wrap the image and button in a div then your .parent() is fine.

Comment: $(this).prev().remove(); $(this).remove(); This is work well thanks :) but I have one more question if you can help me. I want delete image of the database when the remove button is pushed and use  $.get('del.php', function() { alert('Load was performed.'); });    inside the same click function but when push the button if add for example 2 images get function start 2 times

Comment: i dont really understand what you want. Post a new question with more details

Comment: cant tell from that information, and cant really read anythin in this comments... pls create a new question with more information. best would be a http://jsfiddle.net/ or something